# How can I map 5 distinct zone on a draggable-vertical element?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, draggable

I [have](http://jsfiddle.net/2kjaF/4/) this code :

## HTML

```
<div class="draggable_container">
    <div id="draggable_1" class="draggable">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.draggable_container
{
    height:400px;
    background-color:Black;
    width:140px;
}

.draggable
{
    height:60px;
    width:140px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:Red;
}
```

## jQuery

```
$("#draggable_1").draggable({ axis: "y", containment: 'parent' });
```

Well, the height of the container is 400px.
What I'd like to do is to "split" this zone in 5 distinct area (so, every 80px there is a zone) and, when the draggable element enter to this zone, change color to the draggable item.

Example : when I move my draggable to the bottom, for 20px it doesnt do nothing. After 20px, it must change color (let's say blue, for example). Now it still blue for after 80px. Then it change color again... and so on...! The same if I move the draggable element to the top : it must change color every 80px!

Hope it is clear my intention.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use draggable's `drag` event to track position and use some math to determine zone. Below is an example. You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/2kjaF/8/).

```
var colors = [ "#f00", "#0f0", "#00f", "#0ff", "#ff0" ];

$("#draggable_1").draggable({
    axis: "y",
    containment: 'parent',
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.helper.context).css('background-color', colors[Math.floor(ui.position.top / 80)]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks nice! I'd like to avoid that $draggable variable. Can I pass trought the drag:function the reference of the selector?

Comment: Yes, with `ui.helper.context` you can access `#draggable_1` inside `drag` event's function. I'm going to update my answer.